# I want to schedule a task at specific time with timezone specified with using node-scheduler, How should I do it?

Tags: node.js, cron, scheduler, node-cron, node-schedule

Above is my code, which I want to use it as notification scheduler, but not working

```
  const nodeSchedule = require('node-schedule');

  var a = new Date();
  let rule2 = new nodeSchedule.RecurrenceRule();

  rule2.second = a.getSeconds();
  rule2.minute = a.getMinutes() + 2;
  rule2.hour = a.getHours();
  rule2.year = a.getFullYear();
  rule2.month = a.getMonth() + 1; // beware: January = 0; February = 1, etc.
  rule2.date = a.getDate();
  rule2.tz = 'America/Araguaina';

  var job = nodeSchedule.scheduleJob('demo', rule2, function () {
    console.log('worked..');
  });
  console.log(job)
```

Answer (score 1):

i advice you to use cron instead of node-schedule. it gives you more control.

1.you can change cron time without changing the code(SetTime)
2.you have a lot of methods for this library like fireOnTick addCallback etc.
3.can start and stop job dynamically.
4.you have access to onTick and onComplete functions https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron
5.you can set the timezone easily.